# how to use the date (including time) from database as the value of a hidden field in a php table

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have php table and a form field inside the table,  that displays the status of some devices. I am displaying values like Date, Voltage, Current. user can choose any value so that the time corresponding to selected value will be used in the next page for average calculation. For average calculation I should choose immediate 5 values to the selected value. so time value from Date column is important (eg. 2019-04-17 16:14:44). The problem is when i am using hidden form value field, I am getting only date (eg. 2019-04-17) not 'time' .

form.php

```
$sql = "SELECT Date, Voltage, Current FROM DataTable WHERE Date>= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY)  ORDER BY Datum DESC";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $i=1;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<form action = 'formProcess.php' method =get>";

        echo "<tr>

            <td>" . $i. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["Date"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["Voltage"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["Current"]. "</td>


            <td>"." <input type=hidden  name=getTime value =" .$row["Date"]."  </td>
            <td>"." <input type=submit    name=timesubmit value=select  class = classSubmit"."  </td>
        </tr>";
        $i++;
    echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  } else { echo "0 results"; }
```

formProcess.php

```
include("DBconnect.php");

     if(isset ($_GET['timesubmit'])){
       echo "selected a value";
       $selectedTime =$_GET['getTime'];
// the following echo only gives date, not time !! that is the problem.
       echo $selectedTime;
// I wanna use the immediate 5 value, that selected value and immediate 4 values for avg calculation.

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM DataTable 
       WHERE date =>$selectedTime AND ORDER BY Date  DESC LIMIT 5 ";


       $conn= mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db );
       if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
       }




       $result_5_values = $conn->query($sql);
       $i=1;

       if ($result_5_values->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result_10_values->fetch_assoc()) {


           echo "<tr>

               <td>" . $i. "</td>
               <td>" . $row["Date"]. "</td>
               <td>" . $row["Voltage"] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row["Current"]. "</td>

           </tr>";
           $i++;

     }
     echo "</table>";
     } else { echo "0 results"; }


     }else { echo "No selection has been made";}
```

Comment: what is `SHOW CREATE TABLE DataTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT Date, Voltage, Current FROM DataTable WHERE Date>= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY)  ORDER BY Datum DESC";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $i=1;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<form action='formProcess.php' method ='get'>";

        echo "<tr>

            <td>" . $i. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["Date"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["Voltage"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["Current"]. "</td>


            <td>"." <input type='hidden'  name='getTime' value='" .$row["Date"]."'  /></td>
            <td>"." <input type='submit'    name='timesubmit' value='select'  class='classSubmit'"."  </td>
        </tr>";
        $i++;
    echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  } else { echo "0 results"; }
```

The issue is that the you didn't quote the value of the date, all element attribute value should be quoted. I'm expecting in the web source code of this would look like:

`<input type=hidden name=getTime value=2019-04-17 16:14:44>`

It should look like this

`<input type="hidden" name="getTime" value="2019-04-17 16:14:44">`

Comment: Did you try this: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE date <= '$selectedTime' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 5 ";`

Answer (score 0):

As **you have no html quotes**, this will give you just the date for `value`. Have a look at the created html code (you can see that the syntax highlighter of stackoverflow already highlights how the browser sees your html):

```
<input type=hidden name=getTime value=2019-04-17 16:14:44>
```

You should add additional quotes for HTML inside PHPs echo:

```
echo ' <input type="hidden" name="getTime" value="' . $row["Date"] . '" />';
```

... to create a valid html output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="getTime" value="2019-04-17 16:14:44" />
```

To overcome this problem, I would advice you to use single quotes `'` for php and `"` for html. This also has some performance improvements on the php side, but it should not influence your code that much ... ;)

Comment: could you please clarify the issue. Now I am confused. where is the issue?

Comment: The issue are the missing html quotes `"`. `getTime` is a string with a space in between and this space will split the value, so that you only see `2019-04-17` and the time `16:14:44` is ignored. When adding `"` around this datetime (see my last html output), the value is the complete datetime including the space.

Answer (score 0):

**Input tag is not closed**

```
 <input type=hidden  name=getTime value =" .$row["Date"]."  </td>
```

it should be

```
 <input type=hidden  name=getTime value =" .$row["Date"]."/> </td>
```